# Convert PHP function to ASP (classic)

Tags: php, asp-classic

I am trying to convert this little PHP function to ASP(classic):

```
<?php

    function load_partial() {
        $inc_folder = 'partials/';
        $inc_page = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ?
        $_GET['page'].'.php' : 'home.php';
        if (!file_exists($inc_folder.$inc_page)) $inc_page = '404.php';
            include $inc_folder.$inc_page;
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Classic ASP does not allow you to make "dynamic" includes the same way you can do in PHP. In fact real includes (`<!--#include file="myInclude.asp"-->`) in Classic ASP cannot even be parametrized (use a variable to include a file).

However, Classic ASP supports 2 other methods which allow to *execute* the content of an other script, and these methods support a variable containing the script to execute. The methods are `Server.Execute` and `Server.Transfer`. But beware with these methods, because all local variables declared in the calling script will not be available inside of them. So if you want to shared local variables contant you will have to find an other way (Session, File, DB, etc.)

Example :

```
Dim myScript

myScript = "scriptToInclude.asp"

Server.Execute myScript
```

Answer (score 1):

Classic ASP does not have an include directive (well it does, but it is static).

If you want to grab the content of the file and output it to the browser you need to open the file, read it in then spit it back out.

This question may help: [How to read text file in classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695999/how-to-read-text-file-in-classic-asp)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp ?

Comment: You can include a file, but you cannot include a file programmatically.

Comment: you're right, it's even mentioned in my link...my bad!