# A Simple way to Parse HTML

Tags: asp-classic

I have a string that has HTML code that looks like this.

```
<TR ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>TN</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>W</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT>I-40</TD>
<TD>1.7</TD>
<TD>0:01</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT>+I 40 I 440, TN</TD>
<TD>560.8</TD>
<TD>8:57</TD>
<TD>1198.3</TD>
<TD>19:36</TD>

</TR>

<TR ALIGN=RIGHT VALIGN=TOP>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>TN</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>E</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT>I-440</TD>
<TD>4.7</TD>
<TD>0:04</TD>
<TD></TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT>+I 65 I 440, TN</TD>
<TD>565.5</TD>
<TD>9:01</TD>
<TD>1203.0</TD>
<TD>19:40</TD>

</TR>
```

I would like to loop and keep only the 4th and 5th line of each .

```
<TD ALIGN=CENTER>W</TD>
<TD ALIGN=LEFT>I-40</TD>
```

and I would like to combine it into one

```
<TD>W I-40</TD>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Take a look at using the [XML DOM COM Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx).

Comment: The MSXML component is great if you know you have clean XML. Chilkat's XML component is better in some regards. https://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ActiveX.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this. For example, if html has fixed structure, you can [read it line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695999/how-to-read-text-file-in-classic-asp) and count required lines as

```
Dim table: table = false
Dim td: td = 1
Dim s1: s1 = ""
Dim s2: s2 = ""

...

Do Until fs.AtEndOfStream 
    lineData = fs.ReadLine
    if instr(lcase(lineData), "<table")>0 then
        table = true
    else 
        if table and instr(lcase(lineData), "<td")>0 then
        td = td+1
        if td = 4 then
            s1 = replace(replace(lineData, "<TD ALIGN=CENTER>", ""), "</TD>", "")
            lineData = ""
        end if 
        if td = 5 then
            s2 = replace(replace(lineData, "<TD ALIGN=LEFT>", ""), "</TD>", "")
            lineData = "<TD>" & s1 & " " & s2 & "</TD>" & vbClLf
            td = 1
        end if
        end if
    end if
    Response.Write server.htmlencode(lineData) & "<br>"
Loop
```